# Query a specific list of data from Firebase RTDB?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs, behaviorsubject

Is there a better way to query a specific set of data in Firebase RTDB than this?  All I can think of is using forEach() and pushing to a BehaviorSubject inside subscribe on each observable emitted.  Let me know!  I've been stuck on this for a while.

```
hits = new BehaviorSubject([]);

territories = ['16830', '16832', '16838'] // Zip Codes

getTerritories(territories) {
    territories.forEach(key => {
      this.db.object(`locations/${key}`).snapshotChanges()
      .map(zip => zip.payload.val())
      .subscribe(zip => {
        let currentHits = this.hits.getValue();
        currentHits.push(zip);
        this.hits.next(currentHits);
      });
    });
   }

this.hits.subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Observable.forkJoin()`:

```
Observable.forkJoin(
    //this returns an array of observables.
    territories.map(key => this.db.object(`locations/${key}`)
        .map(zip => zip.payload.val()))
)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

Note that `Observable.forkJoin` takes in an array of observables, and fires them in parallel, wait for all of them to complete, before emitting a value.

Comment: I was able to achieve what I wanted with combineLatest.  Thanks for pointing my in the right direction though!